# Depurar StoreProcedure desde SqlServer Management

Tags: sql-server

Buen día a todos el día de hoy tengo una duda ya que no he usado nunca el **depurador de sql server management** y necesito **debuggear** **un stored procedure** en el cual hago varios **insert** a diferentes tablas y al ejecutarlo para un solo registro se queda ciclado.

Si alguien pudiera asesorarme como se realiza el **debuggeo** paso a paso se los agradecería bastante ya que no se como hacerlo y es una herramienta muy importante.

Saludos y gracias de nuevo a todos.

Comment: ¿Que versión de sql tienes?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma corta:

1. Abre una nueva ventana, escribe la ejecución del procedimiento almacenado, por ejemplo suponiendo que tu procedmiento se llama `ObtieneUsuarios`:

   ```
   EXEC ObtieneUsuarios
   ```
2. Posiciona el cursor y teclea <kbd>F9</kbd>, esto para poner un punto de interrupción.
3. Dale clic al botón <kbd>► Depurar</kbd>, o en su caso, <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
4. El proceso de depuración comenzará y ahora el texto `EXEC ObtieneUsuarios` se sombrea en color amarillo.
5. Para entrar a hacer depuración al *Stored Procedure* <kbd>F11</kbd>
6. El depurador entrará al *Stored Procedure*, para ir paso a paso deberás teclear <kbd>F10</kbd>
7. Para dejar correr la ejecución será nuevamente con <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
8. Puedes poner los puntos de interrupción que desees, pero cuando dejes correr la ejecución con la intrucción del punto 7, el depurador se detendrá justo en donde encuentre el siguiente punto de interrupción.
9. Para salir del modo de depuración, será necesario que termine la ejecución del *Stored Procedure*, o en su caso dar clic al botón detener pulsando <kbd>■</kbd>

---

La forma larga, la puedes encontrar en la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh272701(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: Estoy probando esto con la ultima versión de SQL Management, ¿es posible que hayan retirado la opción de debug? ¿O que haya que configurarla? Porque no me sale.

Comment: Lo he probado y no es la solución.

Comment: @Diego talvés no has sabido seguir las instrucciones de manera adecuada

Comment: Empezando... porque no hace referencia ni a la aplicación de la que habla.. lo he probado en el SQL Mangement (No tienen botón depurar) y en una solución de BBDD de VS y en ambos, no concuerda

Comment: Hola, para los que ponían en duda que lo hiciese bien.. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221349/how-to-add-the-debug-button-to-ssms-v18